# New line after input

Tags: python, input, output

I would like to have the following output:

```
Type in something random:
2
```

I used the following code:

```
input("Type in something random:")
```

and my output is

```
Type in something random:2
```

(Output for when the user inputs "2")

How can I have the output given to me in  a new line, as demonstrated above?

I am using Python 3.

Comment: `input("Type in something random:\n")`.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had tried that before, otherwise I would not have asked but seemingly I must have made a mistake. It now works.

Comment: @Austin, you should post answers as answers, not comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a new line character as below

```
input("Type in something random: \n")
```

so that you will get output like this

```
Type in something random:
6
'6'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `\n` (new line character) to the end of the string, like this:

```
input("Type in something random:\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding **\n**

```
print("Type in something random: \n2") 

Type in something random: 
2
```